# How to distinguish between a program’s GUI and Console window?

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, console-application, hotkeys

I have written a code in c# that gets processes by name, activates the window of the desired process and sends some hotkeys to this process. The problem is that the desired process has two windows, a console window and a GUI window, as a result sometimes the GUI window is activated and everything works fine, but sometimes the console window is activated and nothing happens. So my question is, is there a way to distinguish between that process’ GUI and console window, so by program won’t get confused and only activate the GUI window ?

(By activating I mean bringing this process’ window to the foreground in order for the sending hotkeys to work. I have no access to the code of the desired process so I cannot change the way it starts up).

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Use UI Automation.

Comment: I think UI Automation would be useful if the task was really complex. Also, UIA is far more slow that sending simple hotkeys. But thanks for your advice.

Comment: *"Sending simple hotkeys"* tests code paths in your application that a user going through the UI will not hit. If you're avoiding UI Automation, you might as well skip testing altogether. Your "tests" aren't testing the real thing.

Comment: I am not doing any test thing. I just want to automate a simple task. The thing is that sometimes I have to manually minimize the console window and try again in order for the gui window to pop up. So if you know any .NET c# way to distinguish between those two windows of the same program please let me know.

Comment: Assuming your process doesn't already have a console, you can attach to the console of the target process via [`AttachConsole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole). Then call [`GetConsoleWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolewindow) to get the handle of the console window. Finally, detach from the console via `FreeConsole`. With a .NET application, you'll have to P/Invoke these functions.

Comment: Or you could use the window title or window class of the non-console window if it's unique. This isn't as reliable as directly querying the console window handle, but it may be simpler, especially if your process already has a console.

Comment: If this isn't for testing, using UI Automation is still favorable. Changing the foreground process is subject to restrictions and inherently unreliable. UI Automation doesn't require the target to be in the foreground.